# Typecast two model and Return other model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

```
   public static  Coupons.Domain.RejectedCoupons CoupontoRej(Coupons.Domain.Coupon coupon)             {    
            Coupons.Domain.RejectedCoupons a = coupon;   
           return a;
```

Help me out , getting Error ,
    not working for me

```
Error   2   Cannot implicitly convert type 'Com.Arpur.Coupons.Domain.Coupon' to 'Com.Arpur.Coupons.Domain.RejectedCoupons'  C:\Users\Agha\Desktop\Coupon\Com.Arpur.Coupon.User\Helpers\ExtensionMethods.cs  71  48  Com.Arpur.Coupon.User
```

Comment: The error message tells you everything... clearly a RejectedCoupon cannot be directly cast to a Coupon - have you checked that RejectedCoupon derives from Coupon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance it seems that RejectedCoupons is not a base class of Coupons so implicit casting is not going to work (unless to have some implicit conversion operator in place)

Why not create a new RejectedCoupons and fill it with the properties of coupon

```
return new RejectedCoupons {
    prop1 = coupon.prop1,
    prop2 = coupon.prop2,
    ...
}
```